# Js files are not found When i load balanced a angular app in nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, load-balancing, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a angular app what I served in 2 Apache servers both are running perfectly if I run them individually.

But when I set them as upstream to do load balancing. The index file and favicon is found but it can not load the JS files.
it says

> "scripts.f0366af4fa0a9292031f.js net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH 200"

Comment: Old thread. Still, are you building with output hashing enabled?

Comment: @Jayadevan thank you for your response but i could not find the answer yet .i immediately changed the architecture a bit. kept the static files in one server and load balanced the services. only